# why this svg does not fill the screen?

Tags: svg

why this svg does not fill the screen?

i just open "and_gate.svg" (svg below) with last version of firefox/chrome. it doesn't fill height of the screen. (I wrote height because this svg's width:26 height:32.)

```html
 <svg viewBox="0 0 26 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M 0 19 A 13 13 0 0 1 26 19 v 19 h -26 v -19 Z" fill="#000" />
 </svg>
```

however if a svg that width:26 height:32 fills entire height of the screen. (svg below)

```html
 <svg viewBox="0 0 26 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="26" height="32" fill="#000" />
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the two it is clear your path leaves white.. ehm green space

The A(rc) goes from y=19 to y=13 , not to y=0 (top)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 26 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="26" height="32" fill="green" />
  <path d="M 0 19 A 13 13 0 0 1 26 19 v 19 h -26 v -19 Z" fill="#000" />
</svg>
```